# How do I split a single column in a .csv/.xlsx file to multiple columns using a bash command/ linux command?

Tags: linux, awk, csv

In column A, you can see some text which contains "/".[image: files-22-12-12.png]

I want to split column A into 4 different columns using the delimiter "/".

So Year should be in column A, Industry_aggregation_xyz should be column B, Industry_code_xyz should be column C and Industry_name_xyz should be column D.

So basically when I use `awk -F "/" '{print $1}' files-22-12-12.csv`. It prints the output that I want in my 1st column.

`awk -F "/" '{print $2}' files-22-12-12.csv` prints the o/p that I want in my 2nd column.

I basically want to save the o/p of `awk -F "/" '{print $n}' files-22-12-12.csv` in the nth column.

Please help me with a command which can do this.

Comment: `{ print $1, $2, $3, [...] }`

Comment: The program that shows you this table should be able to import the data with an alternate field delimiter.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to replace the image with text. We can't test a potential solution using an image as input. Also make sure to post exactly the output you expect given the input you provide.

Answer (score -2):

```
awk -F "/" '{print $1 ","  $2 "," $3 "," $4}' files-22-12-12.csv > newfile.csv
```

This command works. :)

Comment: But `awk -F / -v OFS=, '{ $1=$1 };1'` would be shorter and not depend on the number of fields per record.  Also, spreadsheet programs generally know how to read and write CSV files with alternate field delimiters.